# Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes c# to java

Tags: java, c#, unicode

i need the same byte in Java

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("asd") //{97, 0, 115, 0, 100, 0} C#
"asd".getBytes() //{97, 115, 100} Java
```

Comment: Check what kind of encoding is being done on each platform

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're calling `getBytes` in Java without passing any charset, so it's using the default one. You want something like:

```
byte[] bytes = "asd".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
```